# Central Limit Theorem with Sample Mean

Tags: mean, central-limit-theorem

Let $X$ is a random variable from the distribution $F$ with mean $\mu$.

As we know, $\bar{X} \equiv \frac{1}{N}\sum \limits_{i=1}^nX_i \xrightarrow{\;\;\;p\;\;\;}\mu$ by LLN (law of large number).

Here, I am wondering whether there is a kind of central limit theorem ensuring
$$\sqrt{N}(\bar{X}-\mu)\xrightarrow{\;\;\;d\;\;\;}N(0, V).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sure there is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT)

> **Lindeberg–Lévy CLT.** Suppose $\{X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb {E} [X_{i}]=\mu $
> and $\operatorname {Var} [X_{i}]=\sigma ^{2}<\infty$ Then as $n$
> approaches infinity, the random variables ${\sqrt {n}}({\bar
>  {X}}_{n}-\mu )$ converge in distribution to a normal ${\mathcal
>  {N}}(0,\sigma ^{2})$:
>
> $$\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}_n - \mu\right)\ \xrightarrow{d}\
>  \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right) .$$